# What type of grout and mortar should I use for the compartment around my wood stove?

Tags: ceramic-tile, tiling

I would like to tile around the inside of my fireplace but I am unsure what type of grout I should use. My only problem is the stove can produce an extreme amount of heat, therefore, causing the tiles to fall off if I use the wrong type of grout.

Is there a type of grout, cement or adhesive that is resistant to extreme heat?

Note: the tiles of which I will be using are fire and heat resistant.

Below is an image of the area within my fireplace of which I am tiling: (note: at the time of tiling the wallpaper will be removed)
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Grout and cement (mortar) are not the same thing. Are you asking about one or the other or both? Also, if your fireplace hasn't caused that wallpaper and wooden baseboard to burst into flame, there's probably no concern with ordinary tile mortar and grout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they have special epoxy mortar for heat sensitive locations.

To me, mortar is what is installed on the back of each tile that fastens the tile to the wall. Grout is what is used to “fill” the joint between each tile. (BTW, this is exactly opposite of terms used for laying concrete block walls...grout is what fills the cells and mortar is what goes in the joint.)

Each “stove” manufacturer have requirements for “non-combustible” clearances between the stove and combustible materials. You’ll need to get the manufacturer’s installation instructions (possibly from the internet).

BTW, you asked about the wall, but you’ll need a non-combustible hearth too. Verify if your current wood floor can remain.

Also, verify the size of your existing flue is acceptable, depending on fuel type, (i.e.: wood, gas, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The stove in the picture was used just for illustration. I have already purchased a hearth and I’ve had an expert visit to install the flue and sweep out the chimney. It will be hard to find manufacturer instructions with this particular stove as it’s from the 1930’s but I’m sure it’ll be okay as there will be no combustible materials close by.